# magento 2 - deploy for custom theme can not complete

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

never seen this one before, when I run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

it passes the luma and blank just fine but when goes to my theme and the backend, it gives only a few dots and without any errors just finishes "succesfully" but the theme have not taken all the changes in the frontend.

```
...........
Successful: 2856 files; errors: 0
---

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2898 files; errors: 0
---

=== Minify templates ===

Successful: 947 files modified
---

New version of deployed files: 1523872033
```

any ideas?

Comment: `-vvv` will get you more verbose output. Also be aware of what mode you are in. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Comment: thank you, I am on default mode still, but it used to run just fine

Comment: i ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -vvv` and now I am even more confused. it seems that it starts with the luma, then goes to my theme, then continues with the luma again, then a little bit of blank and so own....and still no errors. that's odd! i don't get it!